# Python based vba automation?

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have a set of VBA sheets that I'd like to combine to form an online questionnaire. The online applet should also be able to carry out calculations (simple math equations) and plot figures like my excel (VBA) sheets are doing on my pc. I wasn't sure what the best approach would be to achieve this. I am fairly comfortable in Python but have never created a website. In the end I'd like to have a website where my customers can enter details I request and then this performs a set of basic calculations which would result in a basic plot. I don't want my customers to download the programming language I'd use. Is going with Python a good idea? Does anyone have a better suggestion?

Cheers!

Comment: So where would the applet run the python script? Either on my computer or on theirs. Ideally I'd like it to be a standalone feature.

Comment: This belongs on programming.stackexchange.com

Comment: So you want the users to enter data via web page? Do you want to see the chart for all the users, or does each user get to see a chart of their data? Do you want the results in a web page or in excel?

Comment: I want the user to be able to enter information in a questionnaire format and then have my calculations done in excel-vba and then the output as a pdf for the user to download via our webpage.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want data entry in a spreadsheet you can look at, just use a [google form to populate a google spreadsheet](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/87809?hl=en). Then you can add charts and the like to that spreadsheet. You can download a google spreadsheet to an XLSX file for more offline manipulation.

If you have questions about google spreadsheets ask on webapps.stackexchange.com